# Evaluating the integral $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin{x}}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was asked to evaluate the integral

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin{x}}{1+x^2}dx$$

if it exists.

This is a problem from Calculus and the student has been taught how to use trigonometric substitution.  My intuition was to do trig sub with $$x=\tan{\theta}$$ and eliminating $$\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$ but when I do that the numerator becomes $$\sin{(\tan{\theta})}$$ which I am not comfortable integrating.

Another queue was that the problem asks "if it exists" so I tried to see if there are any points within $(-1,1)$ that may cause any problem, but I don't think I see any asymptotes or undefined numbers so I'm not sure if I am dealing with an improper integral.

Can someone help me out on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Zero by symmetry.

It is an odd integrand integrated over a symmetric bound

or more properly "integrated over an interval that is symmetric about the origin".

Comment: Maybe say integrated on an interval symmetric about the origin?

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you it is not my first language english, you helped me.  I added it.

Comment: No problem. Even for native English speakers, math is often tricky :)

Comment: It sure is!  Thank you Ted

Comment: @Integrals What would you say $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xdx$ is?

Comment: @Integrals My point: You must also check for convergence.

Comment: Do you know what differential equation you belong to?  See my post earlier today that deals with convergence in full detail for these kinds of integrals .  Thank you. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793595/convergence-i-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxsdx/793609#793609 @GammaFunction

Comment: I am searching for it too if I find it I shall tell you @GammaFunction

Comment: @Integrals There you go, what a lovely solution x2.

Comment: Wow, it's so funny how blind a person can be when there is such an obvious answer right in front of you.  Thanks.

Comment: @hyg17 No problem...Thank you we are all blind in math

Answer (score 5):

The integral is
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^{2}} dx \\
&= \int_{-1}^{0} \frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^{2}} dx + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^{2}} dx \\
&= - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^{2}} dx + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^{2}} dx \\
&= 0 
\end{align}
where the change of variable $x \rightarrow -x$ was made.

Answer (score 2):

We will begin by evaluating $$I(x) = \int\!\dfrac{\sin(x)}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$

$$I  = \dfrac{1}{2i} \int\!\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x-i}\mathrm{d}x -  \dfrac{1}{2i}\int\!\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x+i}\mathrm{d}x$$

$$I  = \dfrac{1}{2i} \int\!\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x-i}\mathrm{d}x -  \dfrac{1}{2i}\int\!\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x+i}\mathrm{d}x$$

We will now consider $$J_\pm = \int\!\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x\pm i}\mathrm{d}x$$

Substitute $u = x \pm i$.

$$J_\pm = \int\!\dfrac{\sin(u \mp i)}{u}\mathrm{d}x = \int\!\dfrac{\sin(u)\cos(i)\mp\sin(i)\cos(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}x$$

Splitting the integral and using hyperbolic functions

$$J_\pm = \int\!\dfrac{\sin(u)\cosh(1)}{u}\mathrm{d}x \mp\int\!i\dfrac{\sinh(1)\cos(u)}{u}\mathrm{d}x$$

Writing in terms of $\operatorname{Si}(x)$ and $\operatorname{Ci}(x)$

$$J_\pm = \cosh(1)\operatorname{Si}(u) \mp i\sinh(1)\operatorname{Ci}(u)$$

$$J_\pm = \cosh(1)\operatorname{Si}(x\pm i) \mp i\sinh(1)\operatorname{Ci}(x\pm i)$$

$$I = \dfrac{1}{2i}\left(J_--J_+\right)$$

$$I = \dfrac{\left(\cosh(1)\operatorname{Si}(x- i) + i\sinh(1)\operatorname{Ci}(x- i)\right)-\left(\cosh(1)\operatorname{Si}(x+ i) - i\sinh(1)\operatorname{Ci}(x+ i)\right)}{2i}$$

Now evaluate $I$ at $1$ and $-1$.

$$I(1) = I(-1) = -0.324967578038053553$$

$$I(1) - I(-1) = \boxed{0}$$

If you are sneaky you can use symmetry to show that $I(1) = I(-1)$ without actually calculating the value.

Comment: This is not of use to a beginning calculus student.

Comment: @TedShifrin but it is useful to everyone else. The problem is posted for the benefit of the community rather than simply the person who asks the question. This is why "defacing" your own questions is not allowed. If anyone wants to see how they would evaluate this indefinite integral without W|A they can refer to my post instead of posting a new thread. An "acceptable" answer has already been posted.

Comment: This was actually very helpful for me.  Thanks.