# Proving that $\int_0^\infty\sin(x)dx=1$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, fake-proofs

Logically and by method 1 the limit should be undefined, but with some juggling it comes out to be $1$.

- **Method 1.** $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to\infty} \int_0^k \sin(x) \, dx = -\lim_{k\to\infty} (\cos(k)-1) = \text{not defined}$.
- **Method 2.** Let $I = \int e^{-tx}\sin(x) \, dx$ and $J=\int e^{-tx}\cos(x) \, dx$. Using integration by parts,

  \begin{align*}
  I &= -e^{-tx}\cos x - tJ, \tag{i} \\
  J &= e^{-tx}\sin x + tI \tag{ii}
  \end{align*}

  from $\text{(i)}$ and $\text{(ii)}$,

  $$ I = -e^{-tx} \left[ \frac{\cos x + t\sin x}{1+t^2} \right], \qquad
  J = e^{tx}\left[ \frac{\sin x-t\cos x}{1+t^2} \right]. $$

  Thus $\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\sin(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{1+t^2}$. Taking limit $t \to 0$

  $$ \lim_{t\to 0}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx}\sin(x) \, dx
  = \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(x) \, dx
  = 1. $$

Is the integral $1$ or undefined?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: is the integral 1 or undefined.

Comment: @varangrai It is undefined.

Comment: There is no question (not even "where is the mistake?", because the last line is crying "here!").

Comment: It does not converge in improper integral sense, but it has value $1$ in Abel summability sense. It is not surprising that your methods yield different answers as they represent different summability results.

Comment: $\begin{array}{l}t\rightarrow0\;can\;be\;replaced\;by\;t=0\;if\;the\;function\;is\;defined\;is\;defined\;\\at\;t=0,\;which\;in\;this\;case\;is\;as\;f(t)=\int_0^\infty(e^{-tx}\sin x\;dx)\;=\;\frac1{1+t^2}\end{array}$

Comment: Your comment is true, but the caveat is that while $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ is defined on all of $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tx} \sin x \, dx$ is defined only for $t > 0$. So they are *different* functions which happen to coincide on the set $(0, \infty)$ of positive reals. This is in a similar spirit as the geometric series $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} $$ where the left-hand side converges only for $|x| < 1$ but the right-hand side is defined for all $x$ except $x = 1$. You cannot simply plug $x = -1$ to the sum to claim $1-1+1-1+\cdots = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: As a side note, your second method is basically an [Abel sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Abel_summation) of the integral, which has the analogous:$${\small A}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\lim_{x\to0^+}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{-nx}$$

Comment: Oops, the above was already mentioned by @SangchulLee, but I'm going to leave it since it has references and displays the general definition.

Comment: It seems that my question already has an answer here  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral. Thanks for your efforts.;)

Comment: @SangchulLee $1-1+1-1+\ldots =\frac12$ in the sense of Cesáro mean

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Of course that is true. But I can't see how it is related to my discussion as I was talking about the ordinary summability defined as the limit of partial sums. My point was that we should not mix different summability methods.

Comment: Taking the Cesáro mean for integrals, you are basically looking at:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\int_0^n\int_0^t\sin(x)~\mathrm dx~\mathrm dt$$which happens to be $1$ @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: From [this][1] we have (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/794038)
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x^s} dx = \Gamma(1-s) \cos(\frac\pi 2 s) ~~~~0<s<2$$

By letting $s\to 0$ we get; 
$$ \int_0^\infty \sin x dx =1$$



[1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/794038

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your last line what you actually make is

$$ \lim_{t\to 0}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx}\sin(x) \, dx
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}e^{-tx}\sin(x) \, dx$$

This last step is only allowed if the convergence is [uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#Definition). In a sloppy language this means that the "size" of $\sin(x)-e^{-tx} \sin(x)$ is "independent" of x. Which is not the case, that's why your result is wrong.

Comment: "This last step is only allowed if the convergence is uniform." False, it can hold true if the convergence is pointwise. Uniform convergence is a sufficient but unnecessary condition for bringing a limit into an integral.

Answer (score 14):

In your opinion, is it true that
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\lim_{t\to 0^+} e^{-tx}\sin(x)\right)=
\lim_{t\to 0^+}\left( \lim_{x\to +\infty}e^{-tx}\sin(x)\right)\quad ?$$
Switching the order of limits could be dangerous...

See your last line. Are you sure that
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\left(\lim_{r\to +\infty}\int_0^r e^{-tx}\sin(x)dx\right)=\lim_{r\to +\infty}\left(\lim_{t\to 0^+}\int_0^r e^{-tx}\sin(x)dx\right)\quad ?$$

Comment: how about putting $t$ exactly equal to $0$ instead of limit , as everywhere in the solution $0$ is in the domain. in this way we would have $0\times(something\;tending\;to\;infinity)\;= exact 0$

Comment: @varangrai If $t=0$ then $\lim_{r\to +\infty}\int_0^r e^{-0x}\sin(x)dx$ is undefined.

Comment: when you are putting $t=0$ put in the RHS of the equation$(\frac1{1+t^2})$ also. The contradiction formed is my question.

Comment: There is no contradiction, the LHS and the RHS in your last line are not equal. Why do you think that the equality should hold?

Comment: The second last line $(\int_0^\infty e^{-tx}\sin(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{1+t^2})$ is true for all t, hence I put $t=0$.

Comment: No, the second last line is true only for $t>0$. You used that while taking the limit of $I = -e^{-tx} \left[ \frac{\cos x + t\sin x}{1+t^2} \right]$ as $x\to +\infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66576/discussion-between-varang-rai-and-robert-z).

Answer (score 2):

The phenomenon is related to re-summation methods which is a outside my competences, but here is a go:

The first integral 
  $M(u) = \int_0^u \sin x \; dx = 1 -\cos (u)$ indeed does not converge but you may take a Cesàro mean to get a limiting average value:
 $C(t) =  \frac{1}{t} \int_0^T M(u)\; du \rightarrow 1$, as $t\rightarrow \infty$. Unwinding the double integral involed you have:
$$ C(t) = \int_0^t \left( 1 - \frac{x}{t}\right) \sin(x) \; dx = \int_0^\infty \left[ (1-x/t) {\bf 1}_{[0,t]}(x) \right] \;\sin(x) \; dx$$
The factor $(1-x/t) {\bf 1}_{[0,t]}(x)$ goes weakly to one as $t\rightarrow \infty$.

This is  similar to the second method in which you look at the average of $f(x)=\sin x$ weighted by $e^{-xt}$ which also goes weakly to $1$ as $t\rightarrow 0$. You may certainly make other choices that would give a different limit so one question may be if there is a natural family of weights for which the limiting average is unique? (I don't have an answer).