# Find the values of a>0 for which the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{a}} $ converges .

Tags: improper-integrals

Find the values of $a>0$ for which the improper integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{a}}dx$$

converges.

Will the Taylor series expansion of $\sin$ be a better method than testing the integral?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Tell me another way !!

Comment: @sejy you shouldn't use this tone against people that you want help from for free

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793595/convergence-i-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxsdx

Answer (score 1):

We know that $-1\le\sin(x)\le 1$ and so we can approximate the integral with:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)}{x^a}dx\le\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^a}$$
and this integral is convergent for $a>1$ so this narrows our region down to somewhere in $0<a<1$

Comment: It converges also for $\alpha=1$

Comment: @ Henry Lee You should better consider absolute values in your inequalitiy: $| \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}\,dx | \le \int_0^\infty |\frac{\sin(x)}{x^\alpha}|\,dx\le \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^\alpha}\,dx$

Comment: For general $\alpha$ the integral defines the function $\cos \left(\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}\right) \Gamma (1-\alpha)$ by analytic continuation.

Answer (score 1):

For $a \ge 2$ the singularity at $0$ is non-integrable.  For $1 < a < 2$ it's absolutely integrable both at $0$ and at $\infty$.  For $0 < a \le 1$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}  \frac{\sin(x)}{x^a}\; dx$ is an alternating series.